# How do I lookup custom methods in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

If there is a method like `def cookie_monster` somewhere in the project and I'm in a file which is using `cookie_monster`, how do I *quickly* find the file and line where `cookie_monster` is defined?

I saw "[Navigate Code, Not Text: How to Navigate Effectively in RubyMine](http://pivotallabs.com/navigate-code-not-text-how-to-navigate-effectively-in-rubymine/)" from PivotalLabs which says I can use `command + option/alt + O` but perhaps my key mappings are different (default RubyMine 6). That does nothing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I see you got your answer, but that isn't really the best solution, rubymine already caches all the function names and index it to find it fast without doing a search, try this method instead, it should be faster

```
Navigate -> Symbol
```

You'll get a small popup search bar, as soon as you write `cook` you should probably find your function in an auto complete, depending on your layout settings you'll find a nice shortcut to open it.

As a plus there's also

```
Navigate -> File
```

I never search for a file on the side bar to navigate, use this, it's always faster and will list all files with auto complete

The normal find function mentioned is used when you're trying to find a normal line of code, not a name of a function or a file.

Note that in both these popups you don't need to write the full name, for example to open the `cookie_monster` function, you can search for it as this `comon` ( `co` for cookie, and `mon` for monster ) you'll find it fun and very fast.

As for the `find usages` it's common usage for me is to find where a certain partial is called, or a certain function is used.

Comment: You my friend are awesome. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Select the word.

```
Edit -> Find -> Find Usages
```

or

```
Edit -> Find -> Find in Path
```

For keyboard shortcut, use the one against the menu.

Comment: did you select a word before doing that action? Try selecting a common word such as "require"..

Comment: Nothing happens. I highlight the entire word, double tap, click Find Usages and ... nothing happens.. No alert, no pop-up.. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: Latest. Just started using it last week. 6.0.2

Comment: another option -> `Find in Path`

Comment: Mine is 6.0.2. did u try? Edit -> Find -> Find in Path